# Powershell simulate Keyboard

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I have a problem using sendkeys is Powershell. I'm trying to make a script that wil send the keys: shift,w,a,s,d to a game. The code i'm trying is:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(+{w}{a}{s}{d});
```

But when I use this it just sends "Wasd". It won't change the movement, i can see that this has been send in the in-game console.

Is there a way i can simulate the keypresses?

It can by done for the left mouse button using this:

```
    $signature=@' 
          [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
          public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);
    '@ 

    $SendMouseClick = Add-Type -memberDefinition $signature -name "Win32MouseEventNew" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru

$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Is there something similar for the keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

The sendKeys method doesn't seem to support more than one character at a time, so you need to automate sending many keys to the sendkeys method.

After some thought, here's what I came up with.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
timeout 3
'WASD'.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($_)}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Send keys with PowerShell, awesome![1]]

Now, for a line-by-line of what's happening:

- Adding the type, as you did before.
- Next, a three second timeout message, in which I quickly double-clicked and opened Notepad.
- Finally, I'm making a String with the characters 'WASD', then calling the system string `.ToCharArray()` method, which converts a string into an array of characters.  Now I'm working with W,A,S,D, instead of WASD.

For each of those objects (each letter, W,A,S, and D) I'm calling the `SendWait()` static method.  Within a `ForEach` script block, the `$_` symbol is used to refer to the current object.

This the most succinct and easy to understand method I could come up with.

Comment: Hmmm `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{t}{y}{p}{e}{t}{h}{i}{s}{p}{l}{e}{a}{s}{e}")` works here

Comment: Thank you @FoxDeply for you reply, the only problem is that this doesn't solve my problem. The game doesn't seem to accept the SendWait method. My player doesn't stop moving. But when i open something like a chat window it does type WASD. I think it has to be more like the second code i send, for the game to accept it as "real" input.

Comment: The game might have some protection against sendkeys, then.

Comment: @sodawillow, I'm pretty sure it's against Stack Overflow guidelines to down vote other answers to a question you answered.

Comment: I have commented my vote : I simply disagree with the very first statement of the answer : *The sendKeys method doesn't seem to support more than one character at a time*. **If** I broke a rule here, I am sorry. But this is clearly not my understanding of the vote rules. I'll go read the help section right now (no sarcasm here :) ). Moreover I thought the question was more aimed at the shift key than anything else, but I realize I got this wrong.

Comment: One thought, sendWait specifically waits for the other app to acknowledge the key press. What about trying send, or a different method instead?

Comment: Send Doesn't work too. I thought that this might do the trick: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ but this is for C# and i don't know how to use it in Powershell.

Comment: I think this might work too: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendInput , but only i dont know how to use this in powershell

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("+")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{w}{a}{s}{d}")
```

I got `wasd` as a result so I guess it worked.