# passing variable value to external application(e.g Skype) using powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

I am writing a script which basically logs you into any application. Lets use Skype as an example here. So i start skype using:

```
start-process Skype
```

I have the username stored in a variable:

```
$username = "guest123"
```

Once skype opens up, it wants my username. i can't figure out a way to give (pass) the $username value to skype (or username field on skype).

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You've got 2 very simple/common problems.  1) How to pass a username/pw to skype and 2) how to pass params to programs in powershell.  Google this: `skype passing username command line` and then google this:   `how to call program with arguments powershell`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell simulate Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254385/powershell-simulate-keyboard)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I don't want to simulate the keyboard. I want to pass a variable (the username) which can change depending on the user. I get the username by creating an input box and then store what ever the user types in a variable and what i would prefer is some how pass that variable to an application like skype. I have tried using    -Argumentlist  but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: There's no way you can "pass text to Skype" unless Skype supports that, unless you pretend to be a user typing it in by simulating the keyboard.